# Spring MVC - JSON deserialization error - Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I am making an AJAX request sending the following JSON:

```
{"name":"somebody","vehicles":["car","trunk"],"_vehicles":"on"}
```

NOTE: (The _vehicles attribute comes from a form:checkboxes)

The bean that it would be bound is as simple as:

```
public class Person{

    private String name;

    private List<String> vehicles;
```

Before getting to the Spring Controller the following exception is thrown:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@e36df534; line: 1, column: 117] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["vehicles"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@e36df534; line: 1, column: 117] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["vehicles"])
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/new", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json", produces="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Person saveNewPerson(@RequestBody Person person){
```

Dependencies:

- Spring deps 4.2.4.RELEASE
- jackson-annotations/core/databind 2.6.4
- ...(Others resolved by Maven)

web-mvc-config excerpt:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <!-- Default converters -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter" />
            <!-- Jackson 2 -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter" />
            <ref bean="mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>

        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
```

Why can't it be deserialized?

NOTE: If I don't send the vehicles part the deserialization of the Person object works OK.

Comment: Is this the complete version of `Person` class? If it's not, add the missing parts.

Comment: I just omitted the getters and setters.

Comment: Then add your dependencies and your controller that accepts the post request

Comment: How about the receive param in your controller? Can you post it here? Cause your json and Person class is fine.

Comment: I am success to deserialization the new JSON String you post with Rest client, with the same spring version and dont need to setup anything like requestmappinghandler and message converter. I think you need to debug to make sure the form body post to server and may be try to remove some config I mention above.

Comment: On the clinet side, how do you send the the json ?

Comment: @dumitru I send the data with JQuery.

Comment: @Tan Mai Van the message converter thing is part of the company architecture. Anyway the correct converter is applied so it should work...

Comment: If that, did you try to debug and see the form body that browser send to your server? Just want to confirm the raw data you send to server is correct. If you can, please post full header and body of request in the question please.